# How do I edit my blog's author format in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The author in my single blog posts displays as an icon followed by the name (see picture). Instead of this, I want it to display "By: Author's Name" with no icon.

It's been a long time since I've played around with PHP code. My website uses the Integral Pro Wordpress Theme. Can anyone clarify how I can modify this feature?

[image]

Comment: Hey _ I would have directed you to coding on `<?php the_author(); ?>` but that's not going to solve the icon issue _ In fact I suspect you won't need to delve that deeply into code to resolve this _ You haven't given any information on whether you're using plugins that might be responsible for the icon _ Also I'm wondering if you know about this Integral Pro advice page that might be useful >>> https://support.themely.com/section/integral/

Comment: You could hide the icon and then add :before element with `content: "By: "` Just with CSS

Answer (score 0):

That is difficult to answer because there is a lot of things that we don't know, but, the process will be identifying the php file that handles the author display, copy the file over your child theme, edit where appropriate and run to see if it works.